# Launch scrapy shell in an already logged in session

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I need to make some scrapy actions on a web app (e.g. go to links and download files)

But first it's mandatory to log in and set up **manually** some filters (e.g. date).

Only after this manual actions are taken I need to launch the `scrapy shell` from Mac Terminal, starting at the current browser window in my current session.
Added to this, the browser I'm using for this task is NOT my default one.

Any ideas are welcome :)

Comment: You can login from the shell and then go to the other links

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.6/topics/shell.html#invoking-the-shell-from-spiders-to-inspect-responses